# Create new rows in data frame based on multiple values of column

Tags: r, dataframe

#### I have adjusted my question to be a bit more specific

I have searched for a specific answer to my question but without success.

First of all I have a data frame consisting of 48 variables, which looks something likes this:

```
> df

    Text                                               Screen_Name   ...  
1   a text where @Sam and @Su and @Jim are addressed   Peter
2   a text where @Eric is addressed                    Margret
3   a text where @Sarah and @Adam are addressed        John
```

Now I am extracting all strings that equal ("@\S+") and store them in a new column

```
df$addressees <- str_extract_all(df$text, "@\\S+")
```

This gets me:

```
    ...   Screen_Name   Addressees               ...  
1         Peter         c("@Sam", "@Su", "@Jim")
2         Margret       @Eric
3         John          c("@Sarah", "@Adam")
```

Now I want to create a new data frame for the two columns where new rows for each "Addressee" are created by repeating the respective value of column "Screen_Name":

```
> df

    Screen_Name  Addressees
 1  Peter        Sam
 2  Peter        Su
 3  Peter        Jim
 4  Margret      Eric
 5  John         Sarah
 6  John         Adam
```

I have tried solutions to similar approaches, but none of them seems to work.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: how is the column "Friends" stored in the dataframe!!! is it a single string like "Sam, Su, Jim" ?

Comment: @joel.wilson, I understand it to be a list given the c(), although the solution s/he proposes seems to imply a string.

Comment: Does `tidyr::unnest(df, friends)` get you what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. I have adjusted my question, because the solutions do not work for me.

Comment: we have your desired output, could you also tell us what your current output/error is? That may help better understand the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, with a reproducible example:

```
# create df
ego <- c("peter","margaret","john")
friends <- list(c("sam","su","jim"),c("eric"),c("sarah","adam"))
df <- data.frame(ego,friends= I(friends),stringsAsFactors = F)

# use repeat function to repeat rows
times <- sapply(df$friends,length)
df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), times),]
# assign back unlisted friends
df$friends <- unlist(friends)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I made an error, but ultimately it worked well.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try `data.table` using the `df` created by @raistlin:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(friends = unlist(friends)), by = "ego"]

        ego friends
1:    peter     sam
2:    peter      su
3:    peter     jim
4: margaret    eric
5:     john   sarah
6:     john    adam
```

## Edit

*Now, with the additional context supplied by the OP*, the `data.table` solution can be streamlined to solve the underlying problem in a one-liner.

To remove the leading `@` in the `Addressees` column as requested by the OP, the regular expression needs to be modified to use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
library(data.table)

# read data (to make it a reproducible example)
dt <- fread("Text;                                  Screen_Name 
a text where @Sam and @Su and @Jim are addressed;   Peter
a text where @Eric is addressed;                    Margret
a text where @Sarah and @Adam are addressed;        John")

# use str_extract_all with modified regex
dt[, .(Addressees = unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(Text, "(?<=@)\\S+"))), 
   by = .(Screen_Name)]

#   Screen_Name Addressees
#1:       Peter        Sam
#2:       Peter         Su
#3:       Peter        Jim
#4:     Margret       Eric
#5:        John      Sarah
#6:        John       Adam
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

Input:

`Screen_Name <- c("Peter", "Margaret", "John")`
`Addressees <- c(c("@Sam", "@Su", "@Jim"), "@Eric", c("@Sarah", "@Adam") )`

the `tidyverse` way:

`df <- data.frame(Screen_Name, Addressees) %>%
  tidyr::expand(Screen_Name, Addressees)`